# Apache server - show page while server is offline

Tags: html, web, apache-http-server

Since my server is running off my personal laptop, it has quite a lot of down time. Is it possible to have a page that shows up when someone tries to access the site while the server is offline?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a default page for dealing with this and its a 504 error page. You can create custom error pages for your server, but only for things like page requests not being found.

Since your server won't be switched on there is no way for it to serve up your error page. The default should do you just fine though i'm sure.

Comment: 404s are "not found". The closest status code to "server unavailable" is 503, but any error can never be served as you rightly say.

Comment: @CraigWatson 503 is a resource error. Would be a 504 response time error. I have edited as such.

Comment: I stand corrected, downvote rescinded :)

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew says in his answer, your web sever **must** be running to serve any kind of content at all, even error pages.

My strongest possible advice is to move whatever you are hosting **away** from your laptop and onto a proper host - if you are concerned about downtime (or quality of service of any kind) you should **not** be using consumer-grade hardware to host a public website. You can find extremely cheap (or maybe even free) web-hosts online (shopping is beyond the scope of SuperUser).

That said, if you still want to continue hosting the site from your laptop, one solution would be to look into using a CDN of some kind to sit in front of your website's DNS and serve a "sorry page" if your upstream server is unavailable. Notable CDNs are CloudFlare and Yottaa, though these are not recommendations per sé, YMMV.

Comment: Could you suggest any free web hosts? I already have a domain. Just need hosting.